# How use Windows Login in Winforms application to access SAML Service Provider

Tags: winforms, saml-2.0, openid-connect, wif

I'm working with a company that has a WinForms application running on a corporate windows network. The application currently connects to a web application server that has its own private username/password store. The web app server has JSP based UIs, but also has some web services which support JWT based authentication.

The company would like to use use accounts from its windows domain to authenticate the users rather than using a separate set of usernames and passwords. The company's domain has an AD FS server and the web application is a SAML service provider.

The question is, is it possible to use the identity information from the original windows login to get a SAML token from ADFS and then use that token to talk to web services on the web application machine?

We're looking at Windows Identity Foundation built into the .net framework as a possibility. Open ID Connect also seems like a possibility, but we don't want to have to present the user a web page for them to log in; we want to use the original windows login identity information to automatically grant access to the service provider.

Is this possible?

SAML support is already built into the web application, but if necessary we could add support for OpenID Connect.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS does have the ability to [generate JWT tokens](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/maheshu/2015/05/26/json-web-token-jwt-support-in-adfs/) but sadly not for SAML.

There is no way to convert a SAML token to a JWT one that is signed.

SAML doesn't really have support for web API / web services.

WS-Fed does but it's WCF not web API.

The easiest way is to convert to OpenID Connect. That does deliver a JWT token that you can use to authenticate to a web API. You need ADFS 4.0 to do this.

Comment: What about this method for using SAML tokens with an API call: https://www.google.com/amp/s/leastprivilege.com/2012/03/14/asp-net-webapi-security-4-examples-for-various-authentication-scenarios/amp/

Comment: I was thinking about this a little bit more. Thank you for what you've explained already. A few more questions: Why is it that SAML can't support web services? Is that because the protocol for authentication depends on browser redirects and there isn't a browser to redirect in a web api call? Why would ws-fed support a SAML token, but general web services not? ADFS can send back a JWT. Can it generate the token based on the users windows credentials from the local app or does it require showing them a username/password challenge page?

Comment: That's an interesting link. Remember there is a difference between SAML (the protocol) and SAML (the token). WS-Fed also produces SAML tokens. So when I see WS-Trust that kind of points to SAML tokens via WS-Fed.

Comment: There is a SAML profile for "web services" called ECP but it was never widely adopted. Maybe before its time? WS-Fed has two profiles - passive (the normal browser flow) and active (WCF / WS-Trust). But neither SAML nor WS-Fed support REST in the sense of an OAuth JWT. IWA supports logging in under the hood i.e. seamlessly so you don't actually see a login prompt.

Comment: That said there is also SAML 2 Bearer Assertion Flow - https://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/11/19/oauth2-with-saml2.html - but very few IDP support it - neither Azure AD nor ADFS do.